# how to copy history commands in linux to another file via crontab

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, cron

I am using this commands to copy new commands
but these commands not work for me in centos 6.5

```
*/1 * * * * ~/.bash_history >> historylog.txt
```

OR

```
*/1 * * * * .bash_history >> historylog.txt
```

OR

```
*/1 * * * * history | grep -v history >> history.txt
```

how can i do this ? 
if i need any other setting like  ~/.bashrc file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a command to print the contents of the file.

So it would be:

```
*/1 * * * * cat ~/.bash_history >> historylog.txt
```